# Cannot save table to data connection

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, mysqli

I cannot save the table I made which is just a code for a login database, but cannot save it to the actual database

I have looked at the questions related to this and found the same question but it didn't answer it correctly for me. It just doesn't work!

Clicking the update button does nothing to be honest and I need to get in the files of the table to complete my login database from a step-to-step video. The video looked a bit different because it had a dialog box where they could choose the name and it saves under the "Tables" category. Can anyone help me save it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 by the way.

Here is the image: [heree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgPY3.png)

Comment: Try to avoid posting screenshots with your personal email address

Comment: Sorry about that :/

Comment: I think youll be lucky to get an answer to this query to be honest; it's about as easy to answer as saying "I can't feed my cat! here's a picture of my cat! I tried watching a video on how to feed him but it doesn't work! Why not?". Throw away whatever tutorial you're following and follow another one. Here's one example, by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6(v=vs.120).aspx - a nice set of tutorials about datasets, for example

Answer (score 0):

So...are you asking how to create a table? You have the script to create the table in the T-SQL tab at the bottom of your screenshot. Just run a new query on your database and put that in. Or right-click on the Tables folder and select the option to create a new table.

Comment: I've made the table already. But can't save it to the Table category.

Comment: When you pressed "Update", did a window show entitled "Preview Database Updates"? There would be a button at the bottom of that window called "Update Database". Once pressed, the table is created. You need to right-click on the Tables category, as you call it, and select "Refresh" for the new table to appear.